# javascript : key validation

Tags: javascript, validation, keyboard

im using javascript to validate keys in textbox. it is not working :(

```
  function numeric(e) {
        return ((e.keyCode == 8) ||
                (e.keyCode == 9) ||
                (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) ||
                (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) ||
                (e.keyCode == 46) ||
                (e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106) ||
                e.keyCode == 190 ||
                e.keyCode == 110);
    }
```

help me...

Comment: "Not working" is pretty vague. In what way is it misbehaving?

Comment: allows all key values...

Comment: Now with 100% less scrolling ;-)

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: It doesn't allow all key values - e.g. what about `e.keyCode = 10`? I think that would make `numeric(e)` return false.

Comment: using onkeyup="return AlphaNumeric(event)" in textbox

Comment: It might help to have the name in function definition to match the one in event handler... :-)
And maybe try with onkeypress as Pandiya suggests.

Comment: i didnt change my code. but mow its working :)

Comment: Y IT IS WORKING SOMETIME AND SOMETIME NOT WORKING :(

Answer (score 1):

```
function numeric(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if(keycode === 13){
      alert("cheese");
   }
}
```

Comment: This function checks to see if enter was pressed...  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want a numbers only textbox:

```
function numbercheck(event) {
    var unicode = event.charCode; var unicode1 = event.keyCode; if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
        if (unicode1 != 8) {
            if ((unicode >= 48 && unicode <= 57) || unicode1 == 37 || unicode1 == 39 || unicode1 == 35 || unicode1 == 36 || unicode1 == 9 || unicode1 == 46)
            { return true; }
            else
            { return false; }
        }
    }
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") == -1) {
        if (unicode1 != 8) {
            if (unicode1 >= 48 && unicode1 <= 57)
            { return true; }
            else
            { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your textbox call it on the `onkeypress` event:

```
onkeypress="return numbercheck(event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that in I.E. you can set `event.keyCode=0` to suppress the key appearing in the control. But I think you need to trap the onkeydown. Firefox might have an equivalent. This is good because it prevents the key actually "arriving" at the control.

Also keep in mind that you might need to handle combinations of Shift + key and alt + key.

a good debug technique for this sort of thing is to say windows.status = event.keyCode,
and you can see what the keycode is as you type it...

Answer (score 0):

Just try out the following code. I have checked F5 keycode, you can check as you want

```
function disableKey(event) 
{         
  if (!event) event = window.event;
  if (!event) return;
  var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.charCode;
  if (keyCode == 116) {
   showMsg("This functionality is disabled.");
   window.status = "F5 key detected! Attempting to disabling default response.";
   window.setTimeout("window.status='';", 2000);
   // Standard DOM (Mozilla):
   if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
   //IE (exclude Opera with !event.preventDefault):
   if (document.all && event && !event.preventDefault) {
     event.cancelBubble = true;
     event.returnValue = false;
     event.keyCode = 0;
   }
   return false;
  }
}

function setEventListenerForFrame(eventListener) 
{
  document.getElementById('your_textbox').onkeydown = eventListener;
  //frames['frame'].document.onkeypress = eventListener;   
}


<body onload="setEventListener(disableKey);">
```